# Network Manager not controlling any connections

Tags: networking, networkmanager, nmcli

I have created a `vagrant` machine and ssh-ed into it.

`network-manager` was not installed, therefore I proceeded with `apt update && apt install -y network-manager`

However, there seem to be no active connections?

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# sudo nmcli con
NAME  UUID  TYPE  DEVICE
```

How is this possible given that:

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:63:27:9f:3f:f3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

How can I make `network-manager` acquire control over the existing connections so that I can manipulate them via `nmtui` / `nmcli` ?

The `vagrant` box is `ubuntu/xenial64`

Comment: If you installed it properly and started, enabled the services it should work with the existing connection. you can try setting up IP address via the nmcli and reboot to see persistent settings